# Adding specific rows with the same date into a dataframe

Tags: r, merge

I have two dataframes e.g:

```
head (df1)
           Date    v1     v2     v3
       2007-01-01  1      1      Yes
       2007-01-02  2      1      Yes
       2007-01-03  2     1      Yes
       2007-01-04  12     1      Yes
       2007-01-05  3      1      Yes
```

And:

```
head (df2)
           Date    v1     v2     v3
       2007-01-01  1      1      No
       2007-01-01  2      1      No
       2007-01-04  12     1      No
       2007-01-05  3      1      No
```

I would like to add the rows from `df2` to `df1` **only** if they have the same date. The final df should look like this:

```
           Date    v1     v2     v3
       2007-01-01  1      1      Yes
       2007-01-01  1      1      No
       2007-01-01  2      1      No
       2007-01-02  2      1      Yes
       2007-01-03  2      1      Yes
       2007-01-04  12     1      Yes
       2007-01-04  12     1      No
       2007-01-05  3      1      Yes
       2007-01-05  3      1      No
 
I'm sure there is a simple way to do this, I just can't quite find it.
```

Answer (score 1):

We can subset the 'Date' in 'df2' based on the 'Date' column from 'df1' and `rbind`

```
out <- rbind(df1, subset(df2, Date %in% df1$Date))
out[order(out$Date),]
```

-output

```
 Date v1 v2  v3
1 2007-01-01  1  1 Yes
6 2007-01-01  1  1  No
7 2007-01-01  2  1  No
2 2007-01-02  2  1 Yes
3 2007-01-03  2  1 Yes
4 2007-01-04 12  1 Yes
8 2007-01-04 12  1  No
5 2007-01-05  3  1 Yes
9 2007-01-05  3  1  No
```

---

Or using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
bind_rows(df1, filter(df2, Date %in% df1$Date)) %>% 
   arrange(Date)
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Date = c("2007-01-01", "2007-01-02", "2007-01-03", 
"2007-01-04", "2007-01-05"), v1 = c(1L, 2L, 2L, 12L, 3L), v2 = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), v3 = c("Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes")), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))

df2 <- structure(list(Date = c("2007-01-01", "2007-01-01", "2007-01-04", 
"2007-01-05"), v1 = c(1L, 2L, 12L, 3L), v2 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L
), v3 = c("No", "No", "No", "No")), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Comment: Perfect, this has worked a treat. Thank you!